# Setting a max number in c++

Tags: c++

Probably a simple answer, but this has been bugging me for a while now. I seem to have trouble setting a max number. For example, I ask the user for the number of hours used this month, and the maximum number of hours cannot exceed 744. How would I go about setting this maximum number? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: if(numHours > 744) ........

Comment: @pm100 It would probably be better to define a constant rather than using the number directly

Comment: Take a look at one of my answers to a post on codereview:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79839/37893.

Comment: @kgh True but irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use an if statement:

```
if (hours < max_hours) {
  // Do stuff
}
else {
  std::cout << "Invalid Hours";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {

int workhours;
std::cout << "Please enter your workhours: ";
std::cin >> workhours;
if (workhours < max_hours) {
    //good, do your stuff

else {
    std::cout << "Invalid Working Hours";
    std::cout << "Please enter your real workhours: ";
    std::cin >> workhours;
     }}


}
```

Comment: You are missing two `}` characters, as well as meaningful indentation.